# How to apply a texture only to certain parts of mesh?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I am trying to apply a texture to everything EXCEPT the selected parts below (I separated them as a different object to see if this would resolve, but it doesn't...)

[image]

As you can see below, it still adds the texture to the parts I don't want. Any ideas how to fix?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need an object with two or more materials.

1. Under the 'Materials' tab on the right of your interface, click that "+" icon next to your single material, "Material.000".
2. When that happens you get a second material slot to which you may assign faces of your model. Either select a pre-existing material from your drop-down menu, or create a new material to use.
3. Select the faces you want to assign this new material, and with the
   new material highlighted, click "Assign", under the materials list.

You'll see some other useful tools under the materials list that come in handy for assignment and selection.

Comment: Didn't saw it when I wrote my awnser, particulary the same, just without picture...

Answer (score 1):

[image: Test Cube]

You can add two Material Slot's with a copy of your Material and than with face selection you can assign different parts to different Materials